# Aggregating Order Data - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Looking for some advice on data aggregation for a Rails 5 API.

We've got a system which broken down into its simplest components has a Products model and an Orders model.

An Order has_many Products via a product_order join table.

We're generating spreadsheets of orders which contain a summary page with the orders ID, price and order notes and then one workbook per order which lists the individual products for that order.

We also need to output a summary page which contains an aggregated list of all of the Products and the quantity of each product ordered i.e.:

```
Product Summary Table
---------------------
Name------|-Quantity
--------------------
Product 1 | 10
Product 2 | 20
```

etc.

What's the best way to go about aggregating that data?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: You could use a `SELECT product_id, count(*) FROM product_order GROUP BY product_id` query to get quantity for each product.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an API only I assume you expect a JSON response, in that case you could use RABL to render JSON responses (~50ms - ~100ms in rendering time) and still preserve the MVC pattern. Run the queries in your controller and assign them to variables shared between view-controller.

`@products = Product.all.includes(:product_orders)` this will prevent future `n+1` problems

Now having `@products` with `product_orders` loaded in memory you can access to the related data without hitting the database and have access to it in your RABL template.

RABL:

```
object false

node :products do
  @products.each do |p|
    id: p.id,
    count: p.product_orders.count
  end
end
```

in this template, `count: p.product_orders.count` won't hit the database as you already fetched all the `product_orders` to memory.

Now the response will be as:

```
"products": [
  {
    id: 1,
    count: 20
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    count: 21
  },
  ...
]
```

This is what I follow for my API as it respects the MVC pattern.